# Simple React component fails to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to get this simple class to render. Here is my code.

> allView.js

```
var StatCard = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return  (
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="ui statistic">
                    <div class="value">4480</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header">Schools</div>
                    <div class = "meta">matcher</div>
                </div> 
            );
    }  

});

// console.log("Before ReactDOM.render"); -> It doesn't log anything 

ReactDOM.render( <StatCard />, document.getElementById('chartarea'));
```

> HTML File

```
<div id="chartarea"> </div>



</body>
<script type="text/jsx" src="static/js/all/allView.js"></script>
```

I'm relatively new to JS so am unable to do much. **I did the following after reading similar questions and the documentation**

- Capitalized variable
- Added `type="text/jsx"` to the script tag
- Tried using `type="text/babel"` instead
- Placed the script tag at different places even though placing it at the end seems appropriate
- Checked and rechecked closing tags on the element it replaces.
- Included relevant React files as given in their demo fiddle.
- Checked the console (all files load with with a status code of 200)

I placed a console.log statement without the comments and yet nothing shows up on my console.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you included babel script? And how?

Comment: You should place the *ReactDOM.render()* call in a normal javascript file.

Comment: @Maxx Please answer so that I can accept the solution given by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you included babel script? And how?

Comment: Thanks a ton. I spent a lot of time trying to get it to work. What should I include if I use type="text/jsx"

Comment: looks like `react-tools` but i guess it's deprecated, you should use babel (and don't use browser transpilation in production)

Answer (score 1):

Add script type="text/babel" [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shankarrjg/9h0ct2fc/3/)

```
<script type="text/babel" src="static/js/all/allView.js"></script>
```